# CGAffineTransform - Compensate for an upper left transform rotate

Tags: ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I need to apply a translation transformation to compensate for a rectangular view being rotated around (0,0), where the original origin of the view is also 0,0.

The end result should make it appear that the view was transformed around its center point.

```
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(newTransform, angle);
newTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(newTransform,?,?);
```